# how to show all the products laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a query where I show all the products that are in that warehouse, but if it has more than one it shows me the x quantity but with the same data, thats because I have `->first();` but If I remove `->first();` it says an error whit the `traceability`.

```
 $Input = $request->key;
    $almacen = $request->almacen;
$name = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('inventories', 'inventories.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->whereRaw("(products.reference LIKE '%$Input%' OR products.name LIKE '%$Input%') AND products.deleted_at is null")
    ->leftJoin('warehouses', 'inventories.warehouse_id', '=', 'warehouses.id')
    ->where('warehouses.id', $almacen)
    ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
    ->whereNull('inventories.deleted_at')
    ->select(
        'products.reference',
        'products.name',
        'products.sku',
        'products.id',
        'inventories.lot',
        'inventories.expirationDate',
        'inventories.traceability',
        'inventories.warehouse_id'
    )

    ->get();

$array = [];
foreach ($name as $key) {
    //$key->traceability
    array_push($array, $key->reference);
}
//$array = array_unique($array);
$html = '';

if ($name != '[]') {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $prodName = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('inventories', 'inventories.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->where('products.reference', $value)
        ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('inventories.deleted_at')
        ->select(
            'products.reference',
            'products.name',
            'products.sku',
            'products.id',
            'inventories.lot',
            'inventories.expirationDate',
            'inventories.traceability'
            )
            ->first();
            //return $value;
        $html .= '<div><a style="color: #000000" class="suggest-element" traceability="'.$prodName->traceability.'" reference="' . $value . '" sku="' . $prodName->sku . '" name="' . $prodName->name . '" lot="' . $prodName->lot . '" expirationDate="' . $prodName->expirationDate . '" data="' . ($value) . " " . ($prodName->name) . '" id="' . $prodName->id . '">' . ($value) . " " . ($prodName->name) ." " . ($prodName->lot) ." " . ($prodName->expirationDate) ." " . ($prodName->traceability) .'</a></div>';
    }
} else {
    $html .= '<div><a style="color: #000000" class="suggest-element" exist="0" data="Sin coincidencias." id="0">Sin coincidencias.</a></div>';
}
return $html;
```

});`

[image]

I would like to see the products whit the correct data,

Comment: Yeah we need more information.

Please be clear about the current SQL output and the intended one and we can help

Comment: The ocurrent output is like the image all the products has the same information, but not are the same because the last number is different,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently only returning the first row in the database because you are using `first()`.

If you remove `first()`, you will just be left with a `Query Builder` and will get an error like "`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$traceability`" - because you haven't got the data yet.

You can use `get()` instead of `first()` to get **all** of the rows, and this will return a `Collection`.

You can also use `->whereIn('products.reference', $array)` instead of looping through all of the elements in `$array`

You are also comparing `$name` to the string `'[]'` instead of an empty array. You can use `empty()` instead: `if (!empty($name)) {`

And then you can simply loop through the `Collection` and add the html:

```
    // Use empty() - This checks if an array is empty or not
    if (!empty($name)) {
        $products = DB::table('products')
            ->leftJoin('inventories', 'inventories.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            // Use whereIn - This checks if any of the values in $array match products.reference
            ->whereIn('products.reference', $array)
            ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('inventories.deleted_at')
            ->select(
                'products.reference',
                'products.name',
                'products.sku',
                'products.id',
                'inventories.lot',
                'inventories.expirationDate',
                'inventories.traceability'
            )
            // Return all rows
            ->get();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $html .= '<div><a style="color: #000000" class="suggest-element" traceability="' . $product->traceability . '" reference="' . $product->reference . '" sku="' . $product->sku . '" name="' . $product->name . '" lot="' . $product->lot . '" expirationDate="' . $product->->expirationDate . '" data="' . ($product->reference) . " " . ($product->->name) . '" id="' . $product->->id . '">' . ($product->reference) . " " . ($product->name) . " " . ($product->lot) . " " . ($product->expirationDate) . " " . ($product->traceability) . '</a></div>';
        }
    } else {
```